# Send a file from Hadoop to a remote server via sftp

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop, hdfs, sftp

I have some files in a directory on HDFS and I need to move them via SFTP to a remote server.
Normally, what I do is that I download the files from the HDFS to a unix folder with

`hdfs dfs -get /hdfs_path/folder/file.txt /unix_path/dest/path`

and then i move it with sftp as:

`echo "put /unix_path/dest/path/file.txt /remote_folder" | sftp -b - "user@$remoteServer"`

What I want to know: is there any way to do the direct sending of the file via sftp to the remote server from hadoop without needing to do the previous hdfs dfs -get?

Answer (score 0):

[Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/) was created to specifically handle this type of file movement.  (It is a separate install). You should check it out.  I am not aware of another way of doing it unless you wrote some code in spark.

If you want a smaller footprint
I would suggest using [Minifi](https://nifi.apache.org/minifi/minifi-java-agent-quick-start.html) a sub-project of Nifi.
Add [getHDFS](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.GetHDFS/index.html) to Minifi.
This can manage moving data and could be launched from commandline (but Also could run as an agent sending data)

Comment: But in the same shell script? It is possible?

Comment: No Nifi is it's own tooling that is made to move files from hdfs to sftp or anywhere else.  it was written by the NSA to move files.

Comment: Only can be done with NIFI?
Via shellscript is possible?

Comment: I wouldn't use it as a commandline tool, I'd use it as an agent to manage file movement.